# Touch Location Android

Tags: android, screen, background-image

I have a background image and I need to set the touch location!

Like I have a TIC TAC TOE screen as a background and I want the box area to perform respective event when touched. And similarly all other boxes and so on.

so how I would be able to set touch area for all the boxes?
PS: It is just an example.

Comment: Use Buttons or GridView, it´s the simplest way

Comment: its simply hide and show the view brother ,when ever you press any section of your view .for setting up view you can use table view .

Comment: I just need to learn how to set touch area. I can do it other ways.